# First descendant with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to remove the margin above the first h3 element in a table (it looks really weird with a h2 element directly above it)

Is it possible to select the first h3 element?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>I want to select this</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>              
        <td>
            <h3>But not this</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried this:

```
table tbody tr td:first-child h3 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

but I'm failing miserably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach `:first-child` to `tr` instead since every `td` is the first and only child of its `tr`:

```
table tbody tr:first-child td h3 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table tbody tr td:first-child h3 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

td is first child in both the cases, use it on tr or better still add a class to first h3.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers which don't support `:first-child` you can do it in another (reverse) way, to specify a separate style for the next items by select adjacent sibling `tr` with `+`:

```
table tbody tr td h3 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}

table tbody tr + tr td h3 {
    margin-top: 1em; /* any needed value for all following H3's */
}
```

Comment: No browser exists that supports `+` without supporting `:first-child`, so this isn't useful in practice. You may be thinking of `:nth-child(1)` instead.

Comment: In IE7 it is buggy - can be affected by HTML formatting and comments

Comment: What are the odds you'll run into those bugs?